# Sales order number for which sales invoice has not been raised yet

Tags: mysql

How can I get the customer who has a sales account with the company and they placed the order and their items are not shipped, so there is no sales invoice number for them. So I need to find those sales order number for which the items are not shipped (meaning no sales invoice number has been raised for these orders) and those orders are from the customer who has a sales account with us. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You need to provide much more information. What do your tables look like (both in structure and data)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Should show us table structure that you tried?

Comment: I  was trying to find the customer who has a sales account with us. Just trying to find that and then I can proceed with the entire query. Having hard time finding the customer who has a sales account with us.